How to extract the column from a Power BI Hierarchical filter?
When asking what filters are aplied to your embedded report you can ask report.getFilters().
But when the filter that is applied is an hierarchical filter you wilt get the target with the interface:
$schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#hierarchyLevel"
hierarchy: "Hoofdspecialisme - specialisme - specialist"
hierarchyLevel: "Specialist"
table: "Specialist"

No longer are you able to extract column the hierarchyLevel is affecting. This is no problem working within your tabular model where the hierarchies are defined. But i want to query on a db whereon the tabular model is made and herefor i need the column.
Is there any way using the Power BI API/Embedded to translate the Hierarchical target to the real table + column target we all know and love?
I did some research and using the dataSelected event you can inspect the data selected in hierarchical dropdown. Inspecting this data you can see either the hierarchical target and the normal target under "identity". However this is not triggered when you only select a filter in the filter pane. Therefor, when you only select filters there i have not found a way to extract the column whereon the hierarchy is working.
Any suggestions?
